# Using AWK to add DATE to last column of CSV

Tags: csv, awk, jq

As a total bash newbie, I'm struggling to construct an AWK statement that prints the output as a DATE. Here is what I've been trying. Any ideas on how to make the $6 = $date?

```
cat file.json | 
jq -r '.pagedEntities._embedded.teamActivityList | 
  [.[].teamName, .[].rank, .[].average, .[].total] | 
  @csv' | 
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," }  ; {$6=$(date) OFS $6; print}'
```

Comment: I've removed bash tag because this is no bash question/problem.

Comment: Get rid of the UUOC in `cat file.json | jq ...`. Either use `jq ... file.json` or if `jq` can't open a file for itself then `jq ... < file.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in this command...

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," }  ; {$6=$(date) OFS $6; print}'
```

...you are trying to assign to $6 the output of the `date` command, that won't work.  `$(command)` is Bourne shell syntax and won't work in `awk`.  The easiest way to do what you want is probably:

```
awk -v date="$(date)" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," }  ; {$6=date; print}'
```

This assigns the output of `date` to the `awk` variable `date`, which can then be used in your `awk` script.

If that's *not* what you're trying to do, please update your question to show both some sample input as well as an example of what you would like your output to look like.

Comment: Well, I was really close, but your answer was perfect. Thank you for clarifying that you can't use system commands in AWK.

Comment: @AustinS You *can* use system commands in Awk with `system(...)` but it's best practice to just use the shell for that unless absolutely necessary.  To get command output to a variable within Awk, you could do: `...{"date" | getline $6; close("date"); print}` but that's a round about way of doing what the shell can just pass in as a variable.

Comment: @JohnB that syntax is dangerous and so should not be used. You'd need `{cmd="date"; if ( (cmd | getline date) > 0) $6=date; else $6="N/A"; close(cmd); print}` or similar to avoid insidious errors. See http://awk.info/?getline. It's also immensely inefficient unless you need the timestamp to the second to call `date` for every input line so, as you say, it's best just to let the shell set the var up front as shown in larsks' answer.

Comment: @EdMorton I agree that it's better to do the way you suggested.  The other way would certainly be slightly more difficult to debug, but I don't know that it is "dangerous".  To use your suggestion, I'll add that when passing in a variable from shell, you should also do `{if(!date) $6="N/A"; print}`.  The link in the last comment is broken, I think the right one is [awk.info/?tip/getline](http://awk.info/?tip/getline).

Comment: dangersous in as much as if the call to the shell function fails then you'll get no indication of that from the awk script and the variable getline is trying to populate will be populated with the previous successful commands result or be empty if the command never succeeded. It has the other typical getline issues too...

Comment: @EdMoron Got it, then it would indeed avoid many insidious errors.  And thanks for the write up at that link, it has lots of good info.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for an Awk command, but since you're already using jq to generate the CSV file, you might as well do it there:

`cat file.json | 
jq --arg date "$(date)" -r '
    .pagedEntities._embedded.teamActivityList | 
    [.[].teamName, .[].rank, .[].average, .[].total, $date] | 
    @csv'`

This also saves you from the pitfalls of using tools that don't understand the language they're dealing with, as is the case with Awk and CSV; as an example, your script will break if any of the CSV entries is quoted and has a comma in it.

Comment: I thought about posing this as a JQ question, but couldn't find a reference in the jq manual to support doing exactly what you said. Sweet. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Santiago,If you wanted to customize the "$(date)" function to include "$(date %Y-%m-%d %H:%M)" how would the syntax look? My attempts keep failing. Double quotes are making it just insert the text itself.

Comment: Assuming bash: `--arg date "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")"` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which builds on [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3899165/santiago-lapresta)'s approach but uses jq's **now** and **strftime** functions instead of using the unix `date` command.

```
jq -r '
     (now|strftime("%c")) as $date
   | .pagedEntities._embedded.teamActivityList
   | [.[].teamName, .[].rank, .[].average, .[].total, $date]
   | @csv
' file.json
```